# Is a custom "Row" Element for WPBakery (Visual Composer) possible?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I've developed some Elements for the WPBakery Editor and getting better with it. But now I have an idea that I'm not sure if it is possible.

I'd like to build an Element that behaves like the "vc_row" Element, so that if placed in backend it is not nested inside a row automatically.

The background of the problem is (as usual) my customer. The Element should be a "Header" element that is always stretched over the whole page. At the moment my customer needs to add the element, than click on "edit row" and select "stretch row and content" from the dropdown. My Idea is that instead of doing this the element is automatically nested inside a structure that is stretched.

So either the row element must change it's stretching-behaviour based on the nested content (my header-element) or my Element needs to behave like a row itself.

Are there any solutions or ideas for this?

I've read lots of tutorials and of course wpbakery dev manuals but I don't have a clue how to solve the problem.

**+++ UPDATE / Solution +++**

I've found out that if you unminify the code of "assets > js > dist > backend.min.js" in "js_composer" plugin directory and look into line 1408 you will find the following code with two occurences of "vc_section", which is the only "root container" that comes with wpbakery:

```
(e = e.closest("[data-preset]")) && (preset = e.data("preset"), presetType = e.data("element")), !1 === this.model ? (window.vc.storage.lock(), "vc_section" === tag ? (e = { […] && "vc_section" === presetType
```

You can change these lines and add your own element here. Example: If your Element is called "vc_carousel_father" you add an OR-condition.
Just replace `"vc_section" === tag` with `("vc_section" === tag || "vc_carousel_father" === tag)` and `"vc_section" === presetType` with `("vc_section" === presetType || "vc_carousel_father" === presetType)`

After that your Element "vc_carousel_father" behaves like a root-container. Keep in mind that you also have to add the following parameters to your vc_map function in order to make your container draggable on root level:

```
'as_child' => array(
    'only' => '', // Can only be placed in root
),
'class' => 'vc_main-sortable-element',
```

**Important:** To do this you have to modify a core-file of WPBakery. After an update your modifications might be gone or WPBakery stops working.

**+++ How to improve? +++**

If anyone has a good concept how to handle this without the need of a modded core-file I would appreciate your ideas! In the meantime I'm searching for a solution on my own and will give another update if there is one.

My current idea is to add a new parameter to my elements with a true/false option "is root" or something like that. Then maybe there is a chance to hook something in via the "admin_enqueue_js" parameter of wpbakery.

Comment: BTW: I'm in contact with the devs of WPBakery and they've told me that there is no "official way" or even plans to make that possible in the near future so my workaround seems to be the only solution so far. For personal use this works. If you are trying to sell your module / theme you're not allowed to use my solution because of the EULA.